# PHP: Out of memory exception but I've already changed the memory_limit

Tags: php, memory, out-of-memory

I was getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted
```

So, after some research I changed my php.ini file:

```
memory_limit: 2048M
```

The previous error message stoped but I get this error instead:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1746927616) (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in [path]
```

So I've got 2048M as memory limit and in my error the php file allocated 1666M and tried to allocate 256M which give 1922M. This value is smaller than my memory limit so why I am getting this error? (I've checked the php info in my IIS site and the memory limit is the one I mention before).

Thanks :)

EDIT:

Right before the line in which this error ocorred I did a

```
echo memory_get_usage();
```

And I got:

```
1675848
```

The code where's the error is this:

```
for ($i = $startKey; $i <= $endKey; $i++) {
        array_push($paginas, $files[$i]);
}
```

Comment: and did u restart the APACHE after change??

Comment: @devpro I'm using IIS and restarted the server after I changed the memory_limit. And the error message changed after that (to the last one I show in the question).

Comment: You might be hitting the 2Gb per process limit if you're running on Win32. The remaining 120Mb or so are likely used by other PHP data and Apache itself.

Comment: what is your code exactly? such a high value is mostly not an actual memory_limit problem, but a code-design problem. what is your program doing and does it really need 2GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thank you for your tips. It's actually a code-design problem. This isn't my code (I've started working in a already existing project) so it's been a little harder do debug and to decide if I look for some configuration error or assume the code is bad. When I first searched the error I found so many people with the same problem that I stupidly rulled out bad code (and the error was hapening in a part that deals with files).

So, in my case and as suggested here, I start looking my code and used the

```
echo memory_get_usage();
```

To see if all the memory was really been allocated in that line of code and find out that was true. So then I checked the loop variables and sometimes the first one wasn't initalized corretly and the consequence was a no-ending loop.

Thank you all and sorry for the trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate memory, you are actually requesting a contiguous chunk. So, what probably is happening is that have the total memory required, but it's split in two or more chunks.